# Calculating values from a C# windows form application graph

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, math, statistics

I'm conducting a thermal test, where there are 3 setpoint values (with +/1C) I need to confirm.
Setpoints are

1. 37C
2. 60C
3. 80C

I have created a Windows Forms Application where I can upload the data from a "CSV" file and plot it on the application.
[image]
[image]

how do I calculate the average, min, and max values for each setpoint range?
*(red boxes marked are not from the application)*

is there a way to determine a center point for each setpoint and calculate between 2.5 mins either side of the middle?

CSV data looks like this

[image]

any comments to help me towards the right direction is much appreciated

Apologies for the very late reply.
I have updated the question with the Code and a link to the CSV data

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
namespace TBE_Temperature_Contral_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CHART_CH1.MouseWheel += CHART_CH1_MouseWheel;
        CHART_CH2.MouseWheel += CHART_CH2_MouseWheel;
    }

    private void BTN_Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = @"C:\temp",// object of file dialog  sent to open file to default c drive
            Title = "Browse txt File",// text to show on the bar

            CheckFileExists = true,// check whether file exit
            CheckPathExists = true,//check file path

            DefaultExt = "txt",// the file default extensio
            Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*",//filter by default to only txt files
            FilterIndex = 2,
            RestoreDirectory = true,

            ReadOnlyChecked = true,
            ShowReadOnly = true
        };//creation and inialization of open file dialog 
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)// prompt for a file dialog
        {
            string SourcePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[10] { new DataColumn("No."), new DataColumn("Data"), new DataColumn("Time"), new DataColumn("ID"), new DataColumn("CH1"), new DataColumn("Type_1"), new DataColumn("Unit_1"), new DataColumn("CH2"), new DataColumn("Type_2"), new DataColumn("Unit_2") });
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(SourcePath))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    list.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                string[] strlist = list[i].Split('\t');
                dt.Rows.Add(strlist[0], strlist[1], strlist[2], strlist[3], strlist[4], strlist[5], strlist[6], strlist[7], strlist[8], strlist[9]);
            }
            var filteredCH136 = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(r => r.Field<string>("CH1").Contains("36"));
            //dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "No. LIKE '%" + "36" + "%'";
            string FirstCH136 = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                                where (string)dr["CH1"] == "36"
                                select (string)dr["No."]).FirstOrDefault();
            label1.Text = FirstCH136.ToString();

            var filteredCH138 = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(r => r.Field<string>("CH1").Contains("38"));
            //dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "No. LIKE '%" + "36" + "%'";
            string FirstCH138 = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                              where (string)dr["CH1"] == "38"
                              select (string)dr["No."]).FirstOrDefault();
            label2.Text = FirstCH138.ToString();
            CHART_CH1.Series.Add("CH1_36_38");

            CHART_CH1.Series.Add("CH1");
            CHART_CH2.Series.Add("CH2");
            CHART_CH1.Series["CH1_36_38"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            CHART_CH1.Series["CH1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            CHART_CH1.Series["CH1"].Color = Color.Orange;
            CHART_CH2.Series["CH2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            CHART_CH2.Series["CH2"].Color = Color.Blue;
            //CHART_CH1.Series["CH1_36_38"].Points.AddXY(float.Parse(FirstCH136), 36);
            //CHART_CH1.Series["CH1_36_38"].Points.AddXY(float.Parse(FirstCH138), 38);
            CHART_CH1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
            CHART_CH1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
            CHART_CH2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
            CHART_CH2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
            
            CHART_CH1.DataSource = dt;
            CHART_CH2.DataSource = dt;

            CHART_CH1.Series["CH1"].XValueMember ="No.";
            CHART_CH1.Series["CH1"].YValueMembers = "CH1";
            CHART_CH2.Series["CH2"].XValueMember = "No.";
            CHART_CH2.Series["CH2"].YValueMembers = "CH2";
            //databind
            CHART_CH1.DataBind();
            CHART_CH2.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private void CHART_CH1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CHART_CH1.Focused)
            CHART_CH1.Focus();
    }

    private void CHART_CH2_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CHART_CH2.Focused)
            CHART_CH2.Focus();
    }

    private void CHART_CH1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CHART_CH1.Focused)
            CHART_CH1.Parent.Focus();
    }

    private void CHART_CH2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CHART_CH2.Focused)
            CHART_CH2.Parent.Focus();
    }

    private void CHART_CH1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var chart = (Chart)sender;
        var xAxis = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
        var yAxis = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

        try
        {
            if (e.Delta < 0) // Scrolled down.
            {
                xAxis.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
                yAxis.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
            }
            else if (e.Delta > 0) // Scrolled up.
            {
                var xMin = xAxis.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                var xMax = xAxis.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
                var yMin = yAxis.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                var yMax = yAxis.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;

                var posXStart = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) - (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                var posXFinish = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) + (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                var posYStart = yAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) - (yMax - yMin) / 4;
                var posYFinish = yAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) + (yMax - yMin) / 4;

                xAxis.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
                yAxis.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish);
            }
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }

    private void CHART_CH2_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var chart = (Chart)sender;
        var xAxis = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
        var yAxis = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

        try
        {
            if (e.Delta < 0) // Scrolled down.
            {
                xAxis.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
                yAxis.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
            }
            else if (e.Delta > 0) // Scrolled up.
            {
                var xMin = xAxis.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                var xMax = xAxis.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
                var yMin = yAxis.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                var yMax = yAxis.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;

                var posXStart = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) - (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                var posXFinish = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) + (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                var posYStart = yAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) - (yMax - yMin) / 4;
                var posYFinish = yAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) + (yMax - yMin) / 4;

                xAxis.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
                yAxis.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish);
            }
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
}
```

}

C# Winform has two char controls as the CSV has two channels of temp data.

CSV data is saved in Pastebin [C# Temp Data](https://pastebin.com/ChLLWPvi)

I want to check if the temperature is stabilized in the 3 given ranges. it should be stabilized at least for 5 minutes with +/1 degree tolerance. I cannot use min-max and average for the whole list

Comment: :Do you load data from the CSV file in the form of a list? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Are you manually graphing that with custom code or using some kind of control?  Are you currently parsing those date and time columns into valid DateTime instances?  Give us some code...

Comment: Do you know the time frames (index in list) where the set points occur? This question isn't related to winforms or ms-chart. It is just reading csv data and running statistics on the data.

Comment: The 3rd set-point does not look like it is within 1C of 80C. What in the data should be used to find where a set-point is reached?

Comment: Extremely sorry for the late reply. i will edit the question with the code and dataset

Comment: @TheCoder yes i have update the question with the code and a link to the csv data

Comment: @Idle_Mind using the control that's available in Visual Studio 2019 preview community edition

Comment: @JAlex time code and step numbers are generated by the measuring device

Comment: @JAlex yes that's to confirm both true and false conditions, its manipulated to check for validation.

Comment: This is a great start.  Immediately I see that you are simply adding all of that data to your DataTable as straight strings.  You can tell the DataTable the [DATA TYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=netcore-3.1#System_Data_DataColumn_DataType) of each column.  You'll need to parse the data and convert it to each appropriate type before adding those values to a new row.  Once that is done you'll be able to use LINQ style queries to answer questions.

Comment: Thinking out loud here...assuming the data is already sorted by date/time.  I'd find the first date/time entry that is >= 36.  Then I'd keep moving forward and figure out the last entry before you hit something that is >=38.  Now you could compute the time difference between these two entries and divide that by 2.  Find the entry that is nearest to the first entry plus that 1/2 time difference and consider that the midpoint.  Now find all the entries are that plus or minus 2 1/2 minutes from that point and that is your five minute window span.

Answer (score 1):

The running result shows the maximum temperature, minimum temperature, and average temperature within the set value of 37 degrees.

If you want to test the temperature 60, you can replace 60 with 37. (In addition, your txt file does not have 80 degrees.)

I make the following code example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace TBE_Temperature_Contral_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CHART_CH1.MouseWheel += CHART_CH1_MouseWheel;
            CHART_CH2.MouseWheel += CHART_CH2_MouseWheel;
        }

        private void BTN_Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                InitialDirectory = @"D:\TestData",// object of file dialog  sent to open file to default c drive
                Title = "Browse txt File",// text to show on the bar

                CheckFileExists = true,// check whether file exit
                CheckPathExists = true,//check file path

                DefaultExt = "txt",// the file default extensio
                Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*",//filter by default to only txt files
                FilterIndex = 2,
                RestoreDirectory = true,

                ReadOnlyChecked = true,
                ShowReadOnly = true
            };//creation and inialization of open file dialog 
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)// prompt for a file dialog
            {
                string SourcePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[10] { new DataColumn("No."), new DataColumn("Data"), new DataColumn("Time"), new DataColumn("ID"), new DataColumn("CH1"), new DataColumn("Type_1"), new DataColumn("Unit_1"), new DataColumn("CH2"), new DataColumn("Type_2"), new DataColumn("Unit_2") });
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(SourcePath))
                {
                    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadLine());
                        list.Add(sr.ReadLine());

                    }
                }            
                    for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
                    {
                    string[] strlist = list[i].Split(',');                  
                    dt.Rows.Add(strlist[0], strlist[1], strlist[2], strlist[3], strlist[4], strlist[5], strlist[6], strlist[7], strlist[8], strlist[9]);
                    }
                var filteredCH136 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(r => r.Field<string>("CH1").Contains("36"));
                //dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "No. LIKE '%" + "36" + "%'";
                string FirstCH136 = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                                     where (string)dr["CH1"] == "36"
                                     select (string)dr["No."]).FirstOrDefault();
                               
                label1.Text = FirstCH136.ToString();
                var filteredCH138 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(r => r.Field<string>("CH1").Contains("38"));
                //dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "No. LIKE '%" + "36" + "%'";
                string FirstCH138 = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                                     where (string)dr["CH1"] == "38"
                                     select (string)dr["No."]).FirstOrDefault();
                label2.Text = FirstCH138.ToString();
                CHART_CH1.Series.Add("CH1_36_38");


                string FirstCH137 = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                                     where (string)dr["CH1"] == "37"
                                     select (string)dr["No."]).FirstOrDefault();

                string BefNO = (Convert.ToInt32(FirstCH137) - 150).ToString();//Two minutes is 150 seconds
                string AftNo = (Convert.ToInt32(FirstCH137) + 150).ToString();              
                int TmpNum = Convert.ToInt32(AftNo) - Convert.ToInt32(BefNO) +1;
                IEnumerable<double> tmp = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows 
                                             where Convert.ToInt32(dr["No."]) >= Convert.ToInt32(BefNO) && Convert.ToInt32(dr["No."]) <= Convert.ToInt32(AftNo) 
                                             orderby Convert.ToDouble(dr["CH1"]) descending
                                             select Convert.ToDouble(dr["CH1"]));

                double min =tmp.FirstOrDefault();
                double max =tmp.LastOrDefault();               
                IEnumerable<double> TmpSum = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                                              where Convert.ToInt32(dr["No."]) >= Convert.ToInt32(BefNO) && Convert.ToInt32(dr["No."]) <= Convert.ToInt32(AftNo)
                                              select Convert.ToDouble(dr["CH1"]));

                double sum = 0;
                foreach (var v in TmpSum) 
                {
                    sum += v;
                }
                label3.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", sum / TmpNum);//Average value  
                label4.Text = min.ToString();//Max value
                label5.Text = max.ToString();//Min value


                CHART_CH1.Series.Add("CH1");
                CHART_CH2.Series.Add("CH2");
                CHART_CH1.Series["CH1_36_38"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                CHART_CH1.Series["CH1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                CHART_CH1.Series["CH1"].Color = Color.Orange;
                CHART_CH2.Series["CH2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                CHART_CH2.Series["CH2"].Color = Color.Blue;
                //CHART_CH1.Series["CH1_36_38"].Points.AddXY(float.Parse(FirstCH136), 36);
                //CHART_CH1.Series["CH1_36_38"].Points.AddXY(float.Parse(FirstCH138), 38);
                CHART_CH1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
                CHART_CH1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
                CHART_CH2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
                CHART_CH2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

                CHART_CH1.DataSource = dt;
                CHART_CH2.DataSource = dt;

                CHART_CH1.Series["CH1"].XValueMember = "No.";
                CHART_CH1.Series["CH1"].YValueMembers = "CH1";
                CHART_CH2.Series["CH2"].XValueMember = "No.";
                CHART_CH2.Series["CH2"].YValueMembers = "CH2";
                //databind
                CHART_CH1.DataBind();
                CHART_CH2.DataBind();
            }
        }

        private void CHART_CH1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!CHART_CH1.Focused)
                CHART_CH1.Focus();
        }

        private void CHART_CH1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CHART_CH1.Focused)
                CHART_CH1.Parent.Focus();
        }

        private void CHART_CH2_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!CHART_CH2.Focused)
                CHART_CH2.Focus();
        }

        private void CHART_CH2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CHART_CH2.Focused)
                CHART_CH2.Parent.Focus();
        }

        private void CHART_CH1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var chart = (Chart)sender;
            var xAxis = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
            var yAxis = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

            try
            {
                if (e.Delta < 0) // Scrolled down.
                {
                    xAxis.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
                    yAxis.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
                }
                else if (e.Delta > 0) // Scrolled up.
                {
                    var xMin = xAxis.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                    var xMax = xAxis.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
                    var yMin = yAxis.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                    var yMax = yAxis.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;

                    var posXStart = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) - (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                    var posXFinish = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) + (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                    var posYStart = yAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) - (yMax - yMin) / 4;
                    var posYFinish = yAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) + (yMax - yMin) / 4;

                    xAxis.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
                    yAxis.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish);
                }
            }
            catch { throw; }
        }

        private void CHART_CH2_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var chart = (Chart)sender;
            var xAxis = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
            var yAxis = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

            try
            {
                if (e.Delta < 0) // Scrolled down.
                {
                    xAxis.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
                    yAxis.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
                }
                else if (e.Delta > 0) // Scrolled up.
                {
                    var xMin = xAxis.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                    var xMax = xAxis.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
                    var yMin = yAxis.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                    var yMax = yAxis.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;

                    var posXStart = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) - (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                    var posXFinish = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) + (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                    var posYStart = yAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) - (yMax - yMin) / 4;
                    var posYFinish = yAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) + (yMax - yMin) / 4;

                    xAxis.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
                    yAxis.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish);
                }
            }
            catch { throw; }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Jack your solution makes sense to me, Thank you. however, when I'm compiling I get an error in the code line 

IEnumerable<double> tmp 

Ther Error is System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' i have tried multiple changes to the conversion and parsing methods but none had worked for me so far. is it possible to share your full code?

Comment: @rellik, thank you for your reply, I have updated my completed code.

Comment: I tested with a new dataset that has only 36,60, and 80 and the trailing end where the temp is ramping down. Technically this should pass all three criteria but since the LINQ query is looking for 37 it's calculating at the trailing end where it's ramping down. even in your sample screenshot, its showing 44.57,59,36.4 as it has found a 37 in the trailing end, not in the actual 36 setpoint area. I need to rethink this as we are not looking for 37. I want to check in the range it passed.
Still impressive, much further than what i could have been able to push this through.

Comment: If a 37C exists on a sharply rising or falling line, its 36C to 38C time will be very short.Under your setting, a correct 37C, its time between 36C and 38C is maintained for more than five minutes.
So you could find the correct 37C based on this condition.
First, you can find all 37C. If 36C and 38C can be found within 100 seconds before and after it, then this must be an incorrect 37C.
The set value of 100 seconds can be adjusted according to the steepness of the line.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to exactly understand what Setpoint means(pls add some explanation if you can).

However, it is quite easy to perform calculations of Lists.

```
double minvalue = listname.Min();
double maxvalue = listname.Max();
double avgvalue = listname.Average();
```

Comment: apologies I have not used the correct language to explain my problem. I want to check if the temperature is stabilized in the 3 given ranges. it should be stabilized at least for 5 minutes with +/1 degree tolerance. I cannot use min-max and average for the whole list as it would always give me the max value of the whole list and min value - even when is tart the test. same with the average. how do I select the 3 "areas" to calculate these properties individually.?

Comment: @rellik: See, it is sure that you cannot perform calculations based on values of graph. Whatever calculations you do should be done directly through list, which is quite easy. If you could give me 3 example ranges, it would be quite easy for me to help you out!

Comment: sure, can you use the data ranges and the Data in my original question?